# wrapping input value with %% when form submitted jquery

Tags: jquery, forms

Trying to work out how to take a submitted value (whether POST/GET) and prepend/append the submitted value with '%' before the form is actually submitted.

The input id/name is 'm6070bcdx_field[58][fldval]'.

I've tried the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".form-horizontal").submit( function (event) {
        if ($("#m6070bcdx_field[58][fldval]") != '') {
            var cdx58 = $("#m6070bcdx_field[58][fldval]").val();
            $("#m6070bcdx_field[58][fldval]").val() = '%'+cdx58+'%';
            console.log('%'+cdx58+'%');
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Is this for inserting it directly into a sql query?

Comment: Yes - the default action of the form/module is to run a LIKE query, need to add % in order to broaden the search results

Comment: So you're saying, i could, for example, modify your javascript to instead change the value to `"%somevalue%';DROP TABLE users;"` and it'll get inserted directly into your sql?

Comment: Even if you're properly preventing that, it should be a lot easier to do this server-side.

Comment: i'd rather NOT say that, or for that to be the case, but I need to find a method to somehow convert that LIKE search to a 'contains' - any suggestions via javascript/jQuery? as we're trying to avoid editing the core of the module.

Comment: the answer provided already should solve that. The new error you are getting doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Unfortunately, server-side is not feasible for this particular solution as it'd break the module/plugin itself for future updates. Will keep plugging away.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#m6070bcdx_field[58][fldval]").val('%' + cdx58 + '%');
```

Remove the `event.preventDefault()` so that it will still submit your form.

You might want to change it to something like this so that you're not constantly adding '%' to your field:

```
if (!cdx58.match(/^%.*%$/)) {
  $("#m6070bcdx_field[58][fldval]").val('%' + cdx58 + '%');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion robbrit, it doesn't seem to be doing the trick. It's still submitting w/o the % before & after the value.

Comment: further note, the event.preventDefault(); was only temporary, to test and see if the value did get changed. :)

Comment: it appears that the .submit is not actually processing before the form is submitted - tried inserting an alert() on the first line of the function - but it's not being triggered

Comment: @user2228071 is the given script in the <head> of your page? that would cause your script to run before the form exists.

Comment: Hi Kevin, well, I've got that part chased down now. add a $(document).ready(function() { and the submit is now being accessed by the script. 

I am now receiving an undefined error for 'cdx58'